# Scrolling a View by code

Tags: java, android, view, scroll

I want to programatically scroll a `View`. So far, I have found two possibilities :

- `scrollTo(x,y)` : the top left hand corner of the `View` corresponds to the point (x,y) of what must be drawn in the `View`. The problem is that, after the call, it is impossible to manually scroll the `View` to have it displays what is above y or what is at the left of x.
- `setScrollY(y)` : seems to be the function I'm looking for. But it is only available for API above level 14. And my application is supposed to work with API level 8.

Is there another function which could do what I want to do?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: There's a [Scroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) class.

Comment: Good question! Still looking for an answer to this.

Comment: The Scroller class, with custom code, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `View` in a `ScrollView`?  If not, you will need to handle events yourself to manually scroll the View after you use code to set the scroll location.  It sounds like you want both manual and programmatic control, so you'll need to use a scrolling container or handle touch events yourself.